# How to make a one class active and other non active

Tags: html, css

I want to make (see picture below) `popup part` active and `fade part` non-active. I tried but are unable to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: <code>Sample Picture</code>]

**css:**

```
.modal-backdrop,.modal-backdrop.fade.in.his
{
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
} //fader part

// Popup Part

.popup{width: 300px; right: 0px; top: 45px; background: #FFF; position: absolute; text-align: left; display: none; z-index: 100;-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
.popup.active{display: block;}
.popup .row-form{padding: 5px 10px; margin-bottom: 0px;}
.popup .arrow{width: 12px; height: 12px; background: url('../img/popup_arrow.png') left top no-repeat; position: absolute; right: 10px; top: -11px;}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="popup" style="width:322px; height: 452px;">
  <div class="modal-backdrop fade in his"></div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="row-fluid" style="width:322px; height: 452px; overflow-x: hidden">

     <div class="row-form">
           <div class="span12"><strong>SETTINGS</strong></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need Javasctipt ( or Jquery) to add/remove the`.active` class.

Comment: can you give example?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS your'e using class .fader. In html you use fade

Comment: i updated. that was my mistake i am using `modal-backdrop fade in his.`

Comment: Not that into CSS, but I don't think the notation .class.class.class is correct.